# Muting audio and video channels in a Room

Tags: audio, video, twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible via the Twilio SDK for web to stop certain audio and video channels?

Let's say I have a room with members A, B, and C. I have a situation where I want "A" to be able to turn off sending audio/video to "B", but continue sending audio/video to "C"

Also, from the perspective of "A", I need "A" to be able to silence the audio and stop video coming from "B", but continue receiving from "C".

Comment: I believe this can be done indirectly via the Data Tracks API - https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api.

Comment: so are you thinking to send a command message to a user, that user's software will receive the message and mute/unmute appropriately?

Comment: Yes, that is the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need here is [Subscribe Rules](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/track-subscriptions#sl-resource). Subscribe rules allow your application to control the tracks that a participant is subscribed to.

I know Stack Overflow likes that a full answer is shared, not just a link, but subscribe rules can be complicated and I recommend you read through the documentation available here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/track-subscriptions#sl-resource